# What's the best body filler to paint a car

Tags: honda, paint, body, paint-scratches, body-filler

I want to fix some small scratches on my car can you give me some guidance on how I should proceed?

These are my scratches.

Rear bumper
[image: Rear bumper]

Door handle
[image: Handle]

Front bumper. Here the plastic has a deep scratch also.
[image: Frontal bumper]

Comment: Looking at your pictures, I don't think you need any filler.  Just sand down and feather the areas, use a high build urethane primer to fill in any low spots, and paint.  If you need a little filler (I highly doubt you will) an icing product works well for shallow scratches.

Comment: I agree with CBRF23 that you wont need filler. But if you do decide to use it be sure to use a type of filler that is meant for plastics.

I used normal body filler on a plastic bumper and after a while it cracked. The plastic bumper was more flexible than the filler and it changed shape in the heat/cold.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I don't have any experience at all. That's why I didn't know if I needed a body filler because the paint was completely removed arriving to the plastic. I forgot to take another picture from a scratch in the front bumper which I need to level because it is deep on the plastic.

Comment: Seems like one of these comments should be turned into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your pictures, I don't think you need any filler. Just sand down and feather the areas, use a high build urethane primer to fill in any low spots, and paint. If you need a little filler (I highly doubt you will) [icing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GQ1X1MQ) works well for shallow scratches.

Another thought I just had, if the scratches were really deep, you could fill them in/build the area up with a [plastic welder,](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HvV9a3lEe2g) then sand it back down to smooth.

Comment: According to my third pic, the bumper is deeply scratched. So only that case I would need a body filler for plastic. But still don't know a good one. Can't find any on the market.

Comment: Even the third pic I doubt you'll need filler.  Sand it down and feather it out - a couple coats of high build primer and good blocking technique will make that disappear.  If you do end up needing a little filler, like I said, try [icing](https://www.amazon.com/USC-Icing-24-tube-Finishing/dp/B00GQ1X1MQ).  There are some products like polyflex which are marketed as more flexible, but I personally haven't used them so I can't recommend them.  I usually replace plastic bumpers if I can't sand and blend scratches out. Not worth the headache imho.

Comment: Another thought I just had, if the scratches were really deep, you could fill them in/build the area up with a plastic welder, then sand it back down to smooth.